# Using IIS6 run a batch file when particular URL hit

Tags: git, iis, iis-6, githooks, webhooks

We have a git repo on a IIS server (git installed) and when `test.com/updateRepo` is hit it should CD into a particular `dir` and execute  `git pull --rebase origin master` (or execute a batch file)

How do we go about this?

Need it be a .aspx page that will call that batch file?
Can IIS run it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the root folder of your website (Example: C:\inetpub\wwwroot)
2. Create a text file with extension .aspx (Exampe: run.aspx)
3. Add the following script

> ```
> <script language="c#" runat="server">
>
> public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
> {
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\run.bat");    
>   Response.Write("OK");
> }
> ```
>
> < /script>

(You will need to remove the space i addeed for the < /script>, Stackoverflow doesnt allow me to add script tags the correct way.)

Then call the file /run.aspx